# ImportError: No module named networkx on my Mac, conflict with Python versions

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, networkx, conda

I have Anaconda installed on my Mac and Python3.6 as well as Python2.7. I want to import 'networkx' library in my project but I can't, I get the following error:

> ImportError: No module named networkx.

And then I noticed that even though it says that Anaconda uses Python 3.6 when my projects are created in the bin folder is the Python 2.7 version.

Comment: It sounds like you haven't installed the networkx package.  I believe anaconda has a package manager.  Can you check if networkx has been added?

Comment: I have networkx installed, I have installed it via conda and pip as well...

Comment: can you import any other packages that you've installed the same way?